# ViewPagerIndicator with different menu for each page?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-menu

I'm using ViewPagerIndicator to show different pages in a single activity. Is it possible to have a different menu displayed by pressing the menu button on each different page? For example, Page 1 would show "Add" and "Delete" menu items while Page 2 would have "Edit" and "Settings"? These are stupid examples but it the menu seems to be created when the activity is instantiated so when I hit the MENU button the menu has already been created so I get the same menu items no matter which page is currently showing. Is it possible to trigger the onCreateOptionsMenu() when changing the page in ViewPagerIndicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Use Below Method in `Activity`

Override this onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //In this you can Change Menu from different xml  
   // MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
   // if (item != null) {
    // item.setVisible (shouldIShowThisItem)
   // }
//May be you can set Visibility to set for Item to show or Hide

      menu.clear();
    if(menu_one){
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    }else{
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

in this Method you can device which menu you want to display when user Press Menu button in android.as You have Used ViewPagerIndicator ,You known which Page is display and according to that you can make your `switch` condition or `if and else if`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar example. for me i needed a page indicator (that indicate the number of page) for example if i have 4 page i will got for circle images in the menu. when i am in page 3 the third page will be yellow. You can do the same but by adding your necessary buttons.

Here are a simple exemple:
// first the main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class AwesomePagerActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 4;
    private Context cxt;
    private Pager awesomeAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cxt = this;

        awesomeAdapter = new Pager(NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS);
        awesomeAdapter.setContext(cxt);
        awesomeAdapter.setListeImages(liste_images);
        awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    }

    private Integer[] liste_images = {
            R.drawable.tuto_step01, R.drawable.tuto_step02,
            R.drawable.tuto_step03, R.drawable.tuto_step04};


}
```

than the pager adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Pager extends PagerAdapter{

    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    private Context cxt;
    Integer[] liste_images;

    public Pager(int i){
        NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = i;
    }
    public void setContext(Context cxt){
        this.cxt=cxt;

    }

    public void setListeImages(Integer[] liste_images){
        this.liste_images=liste_images;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pager_ind, null);

        ImageView tv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        tv.setImageResource(liste_images[position]);

        LinearLayout mPagesController = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.pages_controller);

        int count = getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i == position)
            {
                ((ImageView) mPagesController.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_vflipper_pressed);
            }
            else
            {
                ((ImageView) mPagesController.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_vflipper_normal);
            }
        }



        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout,0);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

layout_pager_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pages_controller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_vflipper_pressed">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_vflipper_normal">
        </ImageView>   
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_vflipper_normal">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_vflipper_normal">
        </ImageView>    
    </LinearLayout> 


</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/awesomepager"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

You can download the project AwesomePagerIndicator the add your changes like i have done.
Good luck :)